# Normalizing constant of an exponential family of distributions with spherical harmonics

Tags: integration, statistics, spherical-harmonics

I am interested in modeling a distribution on a sphere with a series expansion in terms of the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m (x)$
where $x \in \mathbb{S}^2$ is a point on the unit sphere.
From the paper [Harmonic analysis and distribution-free inference for spherical distributions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X18301155?via%3Dihub) by Jammalamadaka and Terdik I learned that there are multiple ways of achieving this.
The following formulation appears to be suitable in my setting:

> An exponential family of distributions for directional data was introduced in [4] and on p. 82 of [36].
> Apart from the normalizing constant, the density has the form
>
> $$f_e(x) \propto \exp \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} c_l^m Y_l^m (x) $$
>
> where $c_l^{m \ast} = (− 1)^m c_l^{−m}$. The normalizing constant
> corresponds to $c_0^0$ and depends on the rest of the parameters
> $c_l^m$ as well since the integral of $f_e$ must be 1.

I am interested in this normalization constant $c_0^0$.
Following the references in the paper, I could not find an expression for $c_0^0$.
Can anybody point me to a paper or book in which an analytical form (or approximation) is given?

Comment: Update: I decided to approach the problem numerically. I use Lebedev quadrature to estimate the partition function (normalizing constant). Any suggestions or comments here?